# Executing prolog program

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have this pretty simple prolog program

```
min(P1, P2):-
(
  atom_number(P1, L1),
  atom_number(P2, L2),
  (   L1 > L2
  ->  writeln('L2 id min'),
      writeln(L2)
  ;   L1 < L2
  ->  writeln('L1 is mean'),
      writeln(L1)
  )
)
```

I am running it like this from command line -

```
swipl -f pro1.pl
```

als tried using

```
swipl -f pro1.pro
```

and then in prolog terminal

```
min(19,12).
```

gives error:

```
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: min/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

any help>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syntactically, your code need some correction. Let's say I put in x.pl this code

```
min(P1, P2):-
  atom_number(P1, L1),
  atom_number(P2, L2),
  (   L1 > L2
  ->  writeln('L2 id min'),
      writeln(L2)
  ;   L1 < L2
  ->  writeln('L1 is mean'),
      writeln(L1)
  )
.
```

then I can do on the shell command line

```
swipl x.pl
```

and issue some query

```
:~$ swipl x.pl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.1.28)
Copyright (c) 1990-2014 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- min(3,5).
ERROR: atom_number/2: Type error: `atom' expected, found `3' (an integer)
?- min('3','5').
L1 is mean
3
true.

?-
```

Comment: yes, by default .pl it's the accepted extension. I tried, .pro doesn't throw errors, but it doesn't recognize min/2